# Remote Call to ASPX method returning undefined data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, html, web-services

I am new to ASP.NET and web-service. I am calling web service from *.aspx page which returns proper output. But when I call *.aspx method from external HTML page method returns undefined data to AJAX method in success function.

following is my ajax call to *.aspx method

```
// JavaScript Document
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:49367/Ex2/Default.aspx/getHotelMenuList',
            data: '{}',
            contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
            async: true,
            dataType: 'xml',
             complete: function(){
                alert("hi");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); },
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Data:"+msg.d);
            }
    });
});
```

My aspx code is as follow,

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using HotelWebReference;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string getHotelMenuList()
    {
        HotelWebReference.HotelAppForTabWebService proxy = new HotelWebReference.HotelAppForTabWebService();
return proxy.getMenuType();

    }
}
```

Please let me know whats going wrong with my code or what changes should I make in my code.

Comment: Note that your getHotelMenuList() method actually does not return anything !

Comment: sory my mistake I forgot to add return proxy.getMenuType(); while posting code

Answer (score 0):

Several notes:

1) You're not implementing a web service, but a page. Thus, what you're returning is not XML (an this is the expected data on the client side, when you specify `dataType: 'xml'`

2) You're requesting a page, and you are specifying a `contentType` which would be valid for a web service

You can solve this implementign a real web service in your app (*.asmx, or WCF), or, depending on what youu need to get back, use a `jQuery.get()` from the server.